# 301 redirect not working properly with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

http://www.domain.com/thanks.php?orderid=MTI0NjAx

Above url should redirect to 
http://www.domain.com/order-confirmation/MTI0NjAx

But now its redirecting to below url like...
http://www.domain.com/order-confirmation/MTI0NjAx?orderid=MTI0NjAx

I'm using this below code, but not working properly...

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /thanks\.php\?orderid=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /order-confirmation/%1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^order-confirmation/([^/]+)$ /thanks\.php\?orderid=$1 [NC,L]
```

anyone help me, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `?` in target URL to strip off previous query string:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /thanks\.php\?orderid=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /order-confirmation/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^order-confirmation/([^/]+)$ /thanks\.php\?orderid=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Starting with Apache 2.4 you can also use `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag to trip off previous query string.

Comment: I've added your coding, still same problem comes

Comment: That might be due to your browser cache. Completely clear browser cache before testing the chage.

Comment: Yes, after clear cache, now its working fine, thanks